# Can I make Dota 2 use a previous version of OpenGL or "enable" support for 3.1?

Tags: dota-2, graphics-card, ubuntu

So I spent what seems like forever downloading Dota 2 to my Ubuntu PC, only to find out that it requires OpenGL 3.1, which my Intel integrated graphics doesn't support.

Can I make Dota 2 use a previous version of OpenGL or "enable" support for 3.1?

Comment: Can you try to run with DirectX instead? I'm no UNIX guru so that may be a stupid question. Use the launch option "-dx11" or "-dx9" under Properties of Dota 2 in steam library

Comment: You might be able to get some more technical help here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2

Comment: Pls more information about your hardware

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run the game with an older version of OpenGL API. Nor can you "upgrade" your software to add OpenGL 3.1 (or newer) support, unless your hardware itself supports it, and newer drivers are available which enable it.

You need to find the detailed specs of your GPU (or CPU if using internal graphics on Intel/AMD) to see if it supports the version of OpenGL, and then if so, make sure you are using the correct drivers for your GPU. Depending on the GPU you're using, and version of Ubuntu you're on, you may need to switch to different drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing your entire system, it's difficult to help. Dota 2 on Ubuntu has some issues, and I'm not sure your GPU can handle it well - can you perhaps elaborate your system?

I would first and foremost go to launch options and force directX. Either run -dx9 (for directx 9) or -dx11(for directx11) to remove the OpenGL option.

I am, however, afraid you're on a laptop that does not have a good enough GPU(and likely other components) to run the game properly.

Try running `steam --reset` as suggested [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/267)

Comment: I'm using a desktop. You're probably right, might get some lag, but I wanna try and get this working. One sec, I will try your guys' suggestions.

Comment: I tried using both options, but I get the same error: http://imgur.com/q0cXktI

Comment: Don't think that you can use DirectX on linux, without Wine (A program to run windows software on linux). I ran it from the command line and found that multiple directx libraries are missing, which are nowhere to be found on my system or on Google.

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/267), same error. Perhaps that can help. Run `steam --reset` in terminal and get back to us if it worked.

Comment: Linux doesn't support directX.

Comment: I am aware. However, steam and dota 2 can be clunky with Linux. Thus, running `dx9` or `dx11` might work anyhow as to force opengl away(if that's the error)... Anyhow it worked for me when i had issues.

Comment: I don't think those options even exist on the Linux build. At best, they are probably simply ignored.